Batch file, sequence of numbers and strings, how do I handle leading zeroes?
I have a simple batch script that cycles throu an interval of numbers and opens corresponding links also inside an 1,2,3,4 cycle.
The problem is it works fine if I use
start = 10 and end = 150.
But if I do use start = 001 and end = 010, it removes leading zeroes and it's just prefix-1 instead of prefix-001, prefix-002
I want to be able to modify my script so it can handle series of numbers starting with leading zeroes, so if i start at 0001 and end at 0500, the first link will countain 0001 and the last will contain 0500
@echo off

set /p prefix="Insert orefix:"
set /p start="Insert starting number:"
set /p end="Insert ending number:"

for /l %%i in (%start%, 1, %end%) do (
  for %%j in (1, 2, 3, 4) do (
    start "" "https://link?in=%prefix%%%i-%%j&t=01"
    timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
    start "" "https://link?in=%prefix%%%i-%%j&t=02"
    timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
    .....other links
  )
)

UPDATE I AM TRYING THE FOLLOWING TEST:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /p prefix="Insert prefix: "
set /p start="Insert starting number: "
set /p end="Insert ending number: "

rem Determine the length of the starting number
set "start_length=0"
set "num=%start%"
:count_start_length
if defined num (
    set /a "start_length+=1"
    set "num=!num:~1!"
    goto :count_start_length
)

rem Convert start and end numbers to decimal
set /a "start=0%start%"
set /a "end=0%end%"

echo %start%
echo %end%

rem Iterate over the numbers and print with leading zeros
for /l %%i in (%start%,1,%end%) do (
    set "number=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000%%i"
    echo %prefix%!number:~-%start_length%!
)

Somehow start and end are treated as octal and cycling from 001 to 010 is like from 1 to 8.
Trying coverting with
set /a "start=0%start%"
set /a "end=0%end%"

but not working as for now

FOR /L requires integers. And if you read the help file for the set command you would see this: Numeric values are decimal numbers, unless
prefixed by 0x for hexadecimal numbers, and 0 for octal numbers.
So 0x12 is the same as 18 is the same as 022. Please note that the octal
notation can be confusing: 08 and 09 are not valid numbers because 8 and
9 are not valid octal digits.

If you used start = 001 and end = 010 with your original code, you'd have found that the routine also stops at 8, not 10 because for/l woul interpret 010 as octal since the string starts 0.
Please cut-and-paste example code, don't retype it.
I do not like the use of batch keywords as variable-names, hence I've renamed start as begin.
It's normal to start batch programs with a setlocal line, usually after the #echo off line so that any batch run does not pollute the environment (adding, changing or deleting variables within a session)
Since you invoked delayedexpansion in your second example, I've assumed that is valid in this instance.
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /p prefix="Insert orefix:"
set /p begin="Insert starting number:"
SET /a begin=1%begin% 2>NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO invalid begin&GOTO :eof
set /p end="Insert ending number:"
SET /a end=1%end% 2>NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO invalid end&GOTO :eof
IF %begin% GTR %end% ECHO Begin is greater than End&GOTO :eof

:padbegin
SET /a begin=10%begin:~1%
IF %begin% LSS %end% GOTO :padbegin
SET /a begin=1%begin:~2%

for /l %%i in (%begin%, 1, %end%) do (
  SET dummy=%%i
  for %%j in (1, 2, 3, 4) do (
  ECHO %prefix%!dummy:~1!-%%j
  )
)

GOTO :EOF

I've added validity and range checks, assuming you never exceed 8 digits.
Since we know begin is actually < end, we then repeatedly replace the leading 1 with 10 until begin > end, so 1..0100 (begin..end as entered) becomes 11..10100, 101..10100, 1001..10100, 10001..10100, 100001..10100.
Then replace the leading 10 with 1, so the range is 10001..10100 for %%i to iterate.
Within the for loop, set dummy to the value of the iterator %%i and then when used, remove the leading character.
